# laravel Eloquent query collection search again

Tags: laravel

I have one laravel Query as bellow

```
$users=User::with('book')
->whereHas('book', function($query) {
    $query->where(['book.status'=>1]);
    })
->whereNull('deleted');
```

Its working and I am getting results

What I want is
store this result and then group it and store in other varibale

```
$result1=$users->groupBy('status')->get();
```

Now I want to search for users with speficic name

```
$filtered = $users->where('name', 'abc')->get();
```

but when I

```
dd($filtered)
```

it shows all results of $result1

what I am doing wrong and how can I do that?

1. Get query results and use it later
2. group then for other use
3. search them also

Thanks so much

Comment: You can use `refresh()` like `$users->refresh()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This:

```
$users1= clone $users;
$users2= clone $users;
$result1=$users1->groupBy('status')->get();
$filtered = $users2->where('name', 'abc')->get();
```

Comment: Sorry I try but its still same for users2 , thanks so much

Comment: @Mr.SH I edited my answer. I checked it in laravel5.8 and it works correctly. please use it again with two time used `clone`;